# Cheking which menu user clicked

Tags: php, javascript, html

I Want to check my user clicked on which menu? and get it as $_GET for check my condition. How can I do this? Is it OK for when connection Imbalances occurs? It is very important for me.

Comment: what you had tried ?? can you give some code

Comment: for example i have ul li i want o each li you clicked then passed me name of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your li has an id in it:

```
$(function(){
     $('li').click(function(){
          var id = $(this).attr('id');

          $.ajax({
             type:'get',
             url:'getClickedID.php',
             data:'id='+id;
             success:function(result){
                  // do something with returned data
             }
          });
     });
});
```

In your 'getClickedID.php' page, use `$id = $_GET['id']` to catch the value and proceed to do what you wanted to do with it.

Comment: Is it OK for when connection Imbalances occurs?

Comment: What do you mean by connection imbalances? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: for example if i click on a menu and  exactly in that time connection goes down and make a problem

Comment: how can i be sure about every special situation

Comment: You can't. However be advised that the chances of that happening is very very rare. So that shouldn't bother you much.

Comment: you know its very important for my system to be sure .because if dont check correct then it realize other menu instead of its very bad .........